# Cast() doesn't work properly in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, type-conversion

I have a column of image, I want to add a select column (called HasImage) to indicate that if the image is null, the HasImage should have value of false (or bit 0), otherwise the HasImage should have value of true (or bit 1):

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN ImageColumn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS HasImage FROM MyTable
```

I know of **IsNull** function, but I had just tried this before using **IsNull**, when filling the data with the above query into a DataTable, the values are all of long type (not bool as I expected)?

Any idea on why it is like that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ImageColumn IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasImage
FROM mytable
```

Note that SQLite does not have true `BOOLEAN` or `BIT` type. Instead, you can use resultant integer value 0 or 1 as if it was boolean - it typically works great for all intents and purposes, including using it in boolean expressions.

As an example, see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/598ca/1).

Comment: I'm sorry but in fact I used this without casting first, it threw an exception saying the Specified cast is not valid (I tried casting to int in C# code), looking at the cell info in Watch window, I can see the info in Type column is object {long}. I don't understand this, and only casting it to long works. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated answer with [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/598ca/1) - it works great.

Comment: I don't know what it means to my work, I need to execute the query in my c# code, in fact I haven't been able to load the page, it appears to load very slowly.

Comment: @KingKing: Chrome typically works best with sqlfiddle. Can you post your C# code? Since SQLite int is basically always 64-bit, you may need to cast your value to `long` in C# as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4927118/1734130)

Comment: yes, casting to long would work, but I want to use bool or at least int, I have to add that HasImage column to my Table, I think the size of the table will be smaller (and so it's better) when casting it to some type with the smallest size (like bit/boolean or at least int) but all the castings seems to not work except casting to long type. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the real type of the values (as integers) in SQLite depends on the magnitude of the values but no matter what type it is, when getting the values (as objects) and casting to integers in C#, the correct casting is (long), others won't work!

Comment: @KingKing: This may be an issue with .NET SQLite driver. In other languages you don't need to jump too many hoops, and you can even use true `bool` (or `int`, or `short int`) variables. Anything that you cast output value in SQLite will still be technically `INTEGER` (as described in [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) ), and `C#` will still treat it as `long`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SQLite has a "bit" data type.  See this:  http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a bit data type or any others like varchar, nvarchar, char, image, ... but it does support those keywords in the queries. And it understands exactly what we want to use, for example, if I use 'bit' keyword, it would understand that I want to use an Integer of 1 byte (I'm not sure, but it does differentiate from int). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, apparently SQLite supports "non-standard" data names thorough a concept they call "Type Affinity".  Table 2.2 in the document I cited shows that "bit" (BOOLEAN) references are converted to NUMERIC.  I'm learning a lot about SQLite today!